# How to apply Alternatives command to delete cases from a list?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists let say

```
listF = {{7, 2}, {2, 6}, {8, 1}, {1, 7}, {11, 8}, {6, 11}};
```

and

```
newD = {{{2, 7}, {7, 9}, {9, 2}}, {{7, 2}, {2, 6}, {6, 7}}, {{7, 
 2}, {2, 6}, {6, 7}}, {{11, 6}, {6, 2}, {2, 11}}, {{8, 1}, {1, 
 7}, {7, 8}}, {{11, 1}, {1, 8}, {8, 11}}, {{1, 5}, {5, 7}, {7, 
 1}}, {{8, 1}, {1, 7}, {7, 8}}, {{11, 1}, {1, 8}, {8, 11}}, {{11, 
 8}, {8, 6}, {6, 11}}, {{11, 6}, {6, 2}, {2, 11}}, {{11, 8}, {8, 
 6}, {6, 11}}};
```

Question: How can I delete the parts `listF` from `newD` disregarding of the order of elements in the sub-list of `listF`. For example, I need to delete parts from `newD` that whether are in the form of `{2,7}` or `{7,2}`. I would prefer to Apply Alternative command but any solution would be appreciated.

Comment: You could use something like `DeleteCases[newD, Alternatives@@Join[listF, Reverse[listF, {2}]]]` (untested).

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, Thanks for the help.`Alternatives` parts works but there is a trick that `newD` has sub-lists and the code needs to apply to those sub-lists.

Comment: @Mery Tak a look at level spec for `DeleteCases` in documentation. Or you could use: `newD /. Thread[Join[listF, Reverse[listF, 2]] -> Nothing]`

Comment: @LeonidShifrin,@Kuba, Thanks. I got `DeleteCases[newD, Alternatives @@ Join[listF, Reverse[listF, {2}]], 2]`. that woks.

Comment: A minor variant `DeleteCases[newD, # | Reverse[#, {2}] , {2}] &@ (Alternatives @@ listF)`.  To delete just one element from each sublist, maybe: `Function[x, 
  DeleteCases[x, # | Reverse[#, {2}] , {1}, 1] &@ (Alternatives @@ 
     listF)] /@ newD`

Answer (score 6):

You may use `OrderlessPatternSequence` and `DeleteCases`.

Build a set of `Alternatives` with `OrderlessPatternSequence` and `Map` `DeleteCases` over the sublists.

```
DeleteCases[Alternatives @@ ({OrderlessPatternSequence @@ #} & /@ listF)] /@ newD
(*
{
  {{7, 9}, {9, 2}},    {{6, 7}}, {{6, 7}}, 
  {{2, 11}},           {{7, 8}}, 
  {{11, 1}},           {{1, 5}, {5, 7}}, 
  {{7, 8}},            {{11, 1}}, 
  {{8, 6}},            {{2, 11}}, 
  {{8, 6}}
}
*)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I did not know about `OrderlessPatternSequence` command. Looks great for my future works.

Comment: Slightly cleaner maybe: `DeleteCases[Alternatives@@List@*OrderlessPatternSequence@@@listF]/@newD`

Answer (score 5):

```
foo[x_] := Sequence[x, Reverse@x];
DeleteCases[newD, Alternatives @@ (foo /@ listF), 2]
```

> {{{7, 9}, {9, 2}}, {{6, 7}}, {{6, 7}}, {{2, 11}}, {{7, 8}}, {{11, 1}},
>      {{1, 5}, {5, 7}}, {{7, 8}}, {{11, 1}}, {{8, 6}}, {{2, 11}}, {{8, 6}}}

```
fun = ## & @@ (## &[{##}, {#2, #}] & @@@ #) &;
DeleteCases[newD, Alternatives@fun@listF, 2]
```

> {{{7, 9}, {9, 2}}, {{6, 7}}, {{6, 7}}, {{2, 11}}, {{7, 8}}, {{11, 1}},
>      {{1, 5}, {5, 7}}, {{7, 8}}, {{11, 1}}, {{8, 6}}, {{2, 11}}, {{8, 6}}}

**Update:**

> Is there any way that I can delete only one elements from each sub-list in `newD`

Yes... use the fourth argument of `DeleteCases`:

```
DeleteCases[#, Alternatives@fun@listF, 2, 1] & /@ newD
```

> {{{7, 9}, {9, 2}}, {{2, 6}, {6, 7}}, {{2, 6}, {6, 7}}, {{6, 2}, {2, 11}},
>      {{1, 7}, {7, 8}}, {{11, 1}, {8, 11}}, {{1, 5}, {5, 7}}, {{1, 7}, {7, 8}},
>      {{11, 1}, {8, 11}}, {{8, 6}, {6, 11}}, {{6, 2}, {2, 11}}, {{8, 6}, {6, 11}}}

Comment: That's elegant, +1

Comment: @kglr, Thank you

Answer (score 4):

```
Table[Select[newD[[i]], 
  Complement[{#}, listF] != {} && Complement[{Reverse@#}, listF] != {} &]
, {i, Length[newD]}]
```

> {{{7, 9}, {9, 2}}, {{6, 7}}, {{6, 7}}, {{2, 11}}, {{7, 8}}, {{11, 
>      1}}, {{1, 5}, {5, 7}}, {{7, 8}}, {{11, 1}}, {{8, 6}}, {{2, 
>      11}}, {{8, 6}}}

**Remove only one element**

```
Table[Select[newD[[i]],Complement[{#}, listF] == {} || 
  Complement[{Reverse@#}, listF] == {} &], {i, Length[newD]}];
del = %[[All, {1}]] (*choose the first repetition*)

Complement[newD[[#]], del[[#]]] & /@ Range[Length[newD]]
```

> {{{7, 9}, {9, 2}}, {{2, 6}, {6, 7}}, {{2, 6}, {6, 7}}, {{2, 11}, {6, 
>      2}}, {{1, 7}, {7, 8}}, {{8, 11}, {11, 1}}, {{1, 5}, {5, 7}}, {{1, 
>      7}, {7, 8}}, {{8, 11}, {11, 1}}, {{6, 11}, {8, 6}}, {{2, 11}, {6, 
>      2}}, {{6, 11}, {8, 6}}}

Comment: Thanks for the code. Is there any way that I can delete only one elements from each sub-list in `newD`? I mean, I need each sub-list of `newD` have two parts.

Answer (score 0):

Since V 13.1 we have [DeleteElements](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteElements.html)

```
del = Join[listF, Reverse /@ listF];

DeleteElements[#, del] & /@ newD
```

{{{7, 9}, {9, 2}}, {{6, 7}}, {{6, 7}}, {{2, 11}}, {{7, 8}}, {{11,
1}}, {{1, 5}, {5, 7}}, {{7, 8}}, {{11, 1}}, {{8, 6}}, {{2,
11}}, {{8, 6}}}

Answer (score 0):

Using `Delete` and `Position` to delete cases from newD:

```
l1 = listF;
l2 = newD;

Delete[l2, Position[l2, Alternatives @@ Join[#, Reverse /@ #] &@l1]]

(*{{{7, 9}, {9, 2}}, {{6, 7}}, {{6, 7}}, {{2, 11}}, {{7, 8}}, {{11, 1}}, {{1, 5}, {5, 7}}, 
{{7, 8}}, {{11, 1}}, {{8, 6}}, {{2, 11}}, {{8, 6}}}*)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following one-liner does the job.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
listF = {{7, 2}, {2, 6}, {8, 1}, {1, 7}, {11, 8}, {6, 11}};
newD = {{{2, 7}, {7, 9}, {9, 2}}, {{7, 2}, {2, 6}, {6, 7}}, {{7, 
     2}, {2, 6}, {6, 7}}, {{11, 6}, {6, 2}, {2, 11}}, {{8, 1}, {1, 
     7}, {7, 8}}, {{11, 1}, {1, 8}, {8, 11}}, {{1, 5}, {5, 7}, {7, 
     1}}, {{8, 1}, {1, 7}, {7, 8}}, {{11, 1}, {1, 8}, {8, 11}}, {{11, 
     8}, {8, 6}, {6, 11}}, {{11, 6}, {6, 2}, {2, 11}}, {{11, 8}, {8, 
     6}, {6, 11}}};
Pick[newD,
 Map[FreeQ[
    Sequence @@@ (Permutations[#, {Length@#}] & /@ listF)
    , #] &, newD, {-2}]
 ]
```

*Results are at the end of the post*.

The explanation is next.

---

**Step 1**

While comparing sublist entries in `newD` with `listF`, each point in `listF` is supposed to represent all its permutations of the same length as well. For instance:

```
{Permutations[{2, 7}, {2}], Permutations[{1, 5, 9}, {3}]} // Grid
```

[image]

To this end, let's define and augment the `listF` with the proper permutations:

```
listFnew = Sequence @@@ (Permutations[#, {Length@#}] & /@ listF)
```

> {{7, 2}, {2, 7}, {2, 6}, {6, 2}, {8, 1}, {1, 8}, {1, 7}, {7, 1}, {11,
> 8}, {8, 11}, {6, 11}, {11, 6}}

---

**Step2**

A yet unknown function `f` can be directly applied to each entry in `newD` to determine if it (or one of its permutations) is part of/absent from the augmented list `listFnew` .

```
Map[f, newD, {-2}]
```

> {{f[{2, 7}], f[{7, 9}], f[{9, 2}]}, {f[{7, 2}], f[{2, 6}],    f[{6,
> 7}]}, {f[{7, 2}], f[{2, 6}], f[{6, 7}]}, {f[{11, 6}],    f[{6, 2}],
> f[{2, 11}]}, {f[{8, 1}], f[{1, 7}],    f[{7, 8}]}, {f[{11, 1}], f[{1,
> 8}], f[{8, 11}]}, {f[{1, 5}],    f[{5, 7}], f[{7, 1}]}, {f[{8, 1}],
> f[{1, 7}],    f[{7, 8}]}, {f[{11, 1}], f[{1, 8}], f[{8, 11}]}, {f[{11,
> 8}],    f[{8, 6}], f[{6, 11}]}, {f[{11, 6}], f[{6, 2}],    f[{2,
> 11}]}, {f[{11, 8}], f[{8, 6}], f[{6, 11}]}}

To this end a selector function assigns a `True`/`False` after checking absence of membership in the augmented list as required.

```
sel = Map[FreeQ[listFnew, #] &, newD, {-2}]
```

> {{False, True, True}, {False, False, True}, {False, False,    True},
> {False, False, True}, {False, False, True}, {True, False,    False},
> {True, True, False}, {False, False, True}, {True, False,    False},
> {False, True, False}, {False, False, True}, {False, True,    False}}

**Step 3**

```
Pick[newD, sel]
```

---

*Result*

> {{{7, 9}, {9, 2}}, {{6, 7}}, {{6, 7}}, {{2, 11}}, {{7, 8}}, {{11,
> 1}}, {{1, 5}, {5, 7}}, {{7, 8}}, {{11, 1}}, {{8, 6}}, {{2,     11}},
> {{8, 6}}}